# php variable changes when clicked on html link

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink, var

I'm trying to make a game in HTML and PHP and I'm pretty new to coding. The point is I need to execute a PHP script by clicking an HTML element. Is this possible?

My code would look something like this

```
$money = 100;
```

and by clicking on:

```
<a>rob a shop</a>
```

it must excecute:

```
function rob_shop(){
$money += 75;
echo "You now have $money $";}
```

Comment: Google the term AJAX, or look into making a form.

Comment: Strictly, the question can be answered by adding a `href` attribute to that link, but there are still a lot of other missing links (the other type). All in all, this question is too broad, and it's due to your lack of understanding how PHP works (request based).

Comment: your function wont work, $money is out of scope

Comment: @Dagon The question is "out of scope". When did Stack turn into W3School's partners?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have you in my scope cross hairs!

Comment: @Dagon Didn't Robert Plant once say that? grin actually, he said *"...cuz I got you in the sights... of... my .....gun"* lol How many more times? Dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, is PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['money'])) {
    $money = rob_shop($_GET['money']);
    echo 'You now have: '.$money.'<br>';
} else {
    $money = 100;
    echo 'You now have: '.$money.'<br>';
}
echo '<a href="?money='.$money .'">rob a shop</a>';
function rob_shop($money){
    $money = $money + 75;
    return $money;
}
?>
```

But the best way to do it is with ajax to avoid refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add extra param to link and check with php and call function.

```
<a href="?fun">rob money</a>
```

Then check for link

```
if (isset($_GET['fun']))
{
      runFun();
}
```

Comment: Actually, the function is called `rob_shop()` ;)

Comment: I know but it just an idea..

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use javascript and an ajax call or you could just do it in javascript.

```
<a id="shop">rob a shop</a>
<div id="response"></div>

// include jquery
<script>
$( "#shop" ).click(function() {
var money = money + 75;
    $("#response").html( "YOU NOW HAVE $"+money );
// or make an ajax call to a php script and return the value
});
</script>
```